# Making simple Collapse

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-organizational-chart in it's simplest way https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-water-yx1l3g?file=/src/StyledTreeExample.js I need to add collapse to the nodes
I have found this https://codesandbox.io/s/corporate-hierarchy-1pbs0s but I didn't understand how to make the collapse condition on my code cuz it has got two components. this is the only section I need

```
const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = React.useState(o.collapsed);
  const handleCollapse = () => {
    setCollapsed(!collapsed);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    o.collapsed = collapsed;
  });
  const T = parent
    ? TreeNode
    : (props) => (
        <Tree
          {...props}
          lineWidth={"2px"}
          lineColor={"#bbc"}
          lineBorderRadius={"12px"}
        >
          {props.children}
        </Tree>
      );
  return collapsed ? (
    <T
      label={
        <Organization
          org={o}
          onCollapse={handleCollapse}
          collapsed={collapsed}
        />
      }
    />
  ) : (
    <T
      label={
        <Organization
          org={o}
          onCollapse={handleCollapse}
          collapsed={collapsed}
        />
      }
    >
      {_.map(o.account, (a) => (
        <TreeNode label={<Account a={a} />}></TreeNode>
      ))}
      {_.map(o.organizationChildRelationship, (c) => (
        <Node o={c} parent={o} />
      ))}
    </T>
  );
}
```

but how I can do that with my code and this is my code

```
const getLabel = (name) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      {name}
      <div>
        hello
        <button onClick={() => console.log(`clicked ${name}`)}>clickme</button>
      </div>
      <div className="box">N</div>
    </div>
  );
};
const getTreenode = (child) => {
  return child?.map((obj) => {
    return (
      <TreeNode label={getLabel(obj.name)}>
        {obj.child && getTreenode(obj.child)}
      </TreeNode>
    );
  });
};

const StyledTreeExample = () => (
  <Tree
    className="root"
    lineWidth={"2px"}
    lineColor={"green"}
    lineBorderRadius={"10px"}
    label={<div className="card">Root</div>}
  >
    {getTreenode(data)}
  </Tree>
);

export default StyledTreeExample;
```

I don't know Can you help please I really need this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the actual project is using a different approach to populate the tree, compared to the posted example. The specific library also does not seem to provide official instructions on this.

As an experiment, I tried to implement collapse in forked project by making `getTreenode` a recursive component and added a `collapsed` state inside. Some additional styles would be needed, but functionality seems to be working.

Not sure if it might suit the use case, but here is the experimental implement on: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tree-node-test-4o8nzh?file=/src/StyledTreeExample.js)

```
//  Made this a recursive component but kept functionality
const GetTreenode = ({ child }) => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = React.useState({});

  //  Moved this inside component so it handles state
  const getLabel = (name, canCollapse) => {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        {name}
        <div>
          hello
          <button onClick={() => console.log(`clicked ${name}`)}>
            clickme
          </button>
        </div>
        {canCollapse && (
          <div>
            <button
              onClick={() =>
                setCollapsed((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: !!!prev[name] }))
              }
            >
              {collapsed[name] ? "Expand " : "Collapse "}
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="box">N</div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {child?.map((obj) => {
        //  For testing only and should be changed to real unique key
        const timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now() * Math.random());
        const canCollapse = !!obj.child;
        return (
          <TreeNode key={timeStamp} label={getLabel(obj.name, canCollapse)}>
            {obj.child && !collapsed[obj.name] && (
              <GetTreenode child={obj?.child} />
            )}
          </TreeNode>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const StyledTreeExample = () => (
  <Tree
    className="root"
    lineWidth={"2px"}
    lineColor={"green"}
    lineBorderRadius={"10px"}
    label={<div className="card">Root</div>}
  >
    <GetTreenode child={data} />
  </Tree>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is another way to make collapse.

Use `deatils` tag.

```html
<details>
<summary>Click to open</summary>
<p>If your browser supports this element, it should allow you to expand and collapse these details.</p></details>
```

Comment: The question is asking about a specific library the OP is using. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Although this answer is not related to the question, but I liked it! CHEERS!!!